# Most efficient way to download and process a large database (1 GB I think)?

Tags: python, json, database, database-design, data-cleaning

I am looking to download the entire US Government Lobbying Disclosure Act (LDA) Contributions Database and based on some quick math it looks like it will be about 1 GB large (https://lda.senate.gov/api/v1/contributions/).

What is the most efficient way to use the LDA API to download all of this data and create my own database? I have never done a project like this and have no concept for how large this actually is. I am using Python also.

I ask because I don't want to have to keep using the url queries to get the information I need. The lobbyists who filed all of these contributions use alternate spellings and typos when writing in the names of the candidates they donated money to so I am going to use regex or fuzzywuzzy to account for those differences (something I can't pass in the url queries).

Some quick math to make sense of the scale:
(https://lda.senate.gov/api/v1/contributions/)

I used [this](https://www.debugbear.com/json-size-analyzer) JSON size analyzer to get the size of page 1/19,892 of the database and it said it is 50.2 KB.

50.2 KB * 19892 = .998 GB (size of entire database)

My previous database where I tediously queried each of the few dozen candidates has a csv file that is 22.1 MB (.0221 GB) and has 30,852 rows of data.

So 30,852 rows / .0221 GB = 1,396,018 rows for 1 GB?
Does this math follow, and if so, is this a crazy large database?

Would it take a very long time to download all of this, and once I have the database, is it going to be very slow if I wanted to iterate through the entire database to select for the specific candidates that I want (esp. when using tools like regex)?

Do I want to use an iJson for this?

Also would csv be the best file format to store this data?

Again I have no clue if this is a massive dataset that will crash my code and computer or if this is peanuts to what some of you professionals are doing on a daily basis.

Thank you so much for any help on this!

Comment: How often are you going to download the entire database?  My suggestion is to download the entire database as JSON, process the JSON as much as you possibly can by correcting misspelled names, and writing the corrected information to a relational database.  If it takes two days to download the database, it's two days once every few weeks or months.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you after download, use AVL tree method to indexing the database. AVL tree requires long time to make the searching index but after that you Will have a very fast way to find specific candidate you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Emilio! Wondering what would be the fastest way to fetch all of the data with python. I read that for loops are much slower and perhaps another method could allow me to download the data to a csv file much faster?

Comment: I'm not expert to download but after download,

I have 4 Gbyte DataBase consisting in 80000 files, using python with AVL tree methods,

it takes 100 hours to generate 1286012 index files.

After that I am able to reach every single fetch in 50 msec. It's very fast, doesn't it?

It's complicated I know, and also if you need often modify the content of Db it takes long time, for me medium each single modification takes few sec.